# TinyMCE - populate dynamically an iframe created on paste event

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

My code is creating an iframe on PastePostProcess event in TinyMCE.

After a jquery post - which will be used later on to populate the iframe - the iframe is populated by using its hard coded id : **editor.dom.select("[id='aaa']")**. So far, it works if there is only one iframe in the editor.

I would like to populate the iframe using the local **e.node** variable passed through the PastePostProcess event.

Whe using **e.node.firstChild.firstChild**, I get stucked by the fact that its **.contentDocument** property is null.

You can copy/paste the code in http://fiddle.tinymce.com/, drag and drop something external to the editor, and see the problem with e.node in the console.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea"
    ,plugins: 'paste'
    ,height:300
    ,extended_valid_elements : "iframe[* ], div[* ]"
    ,init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
      editor.on('PastePostProcess', function (e) {
        e.node.innerHTML='<div><iframe id="aaa" style="width:450px;" src="about:blank"></iframe></div>';
        $.post("..", {}, function (data) {

        console.log(e.node.firstChild.firstChild);  // ok
        console.log(e.node.firstChild.firstChild.contentDocument);  // KO (null)

        console.log(editor.dom.select("[id='aaa']")[0]);  // ok
        console.log(editor.dom.select("[id='aaa']")[0].contentDocument);  // ok (HTMLDocument)

        var msg="The iframe has been populated using hard-coded id='aaa'<br/>";
        msg=msg+"How to populate the iframe using the e.node local variable?<br/>";

        editor.dom.select("[id='aaa']")[0].contentDocument.write(msg);
      })
    })
  }
});
</script>

<textarea name="content">Please drag and drop something below<br/><br/><br/></textarea>
```

It seems to me that I am close to the solution, targeting dynamically the newly created iframe. What am I missing to achieve that?

Comment: The problem is $.post is asynchronous and e does not exist anymore when the post function is executed. A workaround is to generate a random id, like https://gist.github.com/gordonbrander/2230317. It's not elegant but it works. I post the answer for reference and leave it open for a moment in case someone finds a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented above, here is a 'not so nice' solution using a random id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var random_id;
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea"
    ,plugins: 'paste'
    ,height:300
    ,extended_valid_elements : "iframe[* ], div[* ]"
    ,init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
      editor.on('PastePostProcess', function (e) {
      random_id='_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,9); // generate random id
        e.node.innerHTML='<div><iframe id="' + random_id + '" style="width:450px;" src="about:blank"></iframe></div>';
        $.post("..", {}, function (data) {
        var msg="The iframe has been populated using random id : " + random_id + "<br/>";
        editor.dom.select("[id=" + random_id + "]")[0].contentDocument.write(msg);
      })
    })
  }
});
</script>

<textarea name="content">Please drag and drop something below<br/><br/><br/></textarea>
```